# Github Pages Deployment through Node

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, terminal, github-pages

I have refactored a repo on GitHub, I would like to deploy my changes to a GitHub page. I can't seem to get the new changes to deploy to Github pages. I am using Node, React, and visual studio code.
I have tried "npm run build" in the terminal quite a few times. This won't show my new changes. If anything, it will deploy my old code.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I was not running "npm run build" and then "npm run deploy" right after. And, my gh-pages was being created from the wrong branch.

Comment: How does your `npm run build` looks like in `package.json`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.